# Implementing Secret Sharing with an Encrypted Bitcoin Wallet

Tags: wallet, encryption

How would I implement [Shamir's Secret Sharing Scheme](http://point-at-infinity.org/ssss/) with an encrypted Bitcoin wallet?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve?  SSSS works in principle with any arbitrary data, so you could certainly use a Bitcoin wallet file as the secret to be shared.  You could also just use the wallet's encryption passphrase as the secret.

Comment: @NateEldredge See [this](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=781463.msg8830810#msg8830810). Someone also recommended [Blind signatures](http://blog.oleganza.com/post/77474860538/blind-signatures). I'm not really sure what the best way of implementing either of these schemes is, though. I wouldn't want to use the wallet's passphrase because I don't want the user decrypting the wallet to know the passphrase.